# Is there a way to set a variable equal to the cell address of a comment in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I want some code that will search a worksheet for comments and return the address of a cell containing a particular comment.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Public Sub CommentLocator()

Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim cmt As Comment
Dim StartCell As Variant

Set Sht = Sheet06

For Each cmt In Sht.Comments
    If cmt.Text = "$StartCell" Then
        Set StartCell = Range(cmt.Parent.Address)
        Debug.Print cmt.Parent.Address
    End If
Next cmt

End Sub
```

The problem is that this sets my variable `StartCell` to the *value contained within* the cell.  But, I want it instead to return the *address of* the cell.

I've tried getting rid of the `Range`, but this results in a *"Run-time error 13: Type mismatch"*.

I've tried adding `.Address` after the `Range` or the `Range(cmt.Parent.Address)`, but this results in a *"Compile Error: Argument not optional"* or a *"Compile Error: Object required"*.

I feel like I'm close, but can't quite get this to work on my own.

I'd really appreciate any help anyone can give me here.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the Range() there:

Set StartCell = cmt.Parent

As a String:

Startcell = cmt.Parent.Address

Comment: Using:

`Set StartCell = cmt.Parent`

Sets my variable `StartCell` to the value contained within the cell.  I want to set `StartCell` to the address of the cell instead.

Your second suggestion works perfectly though.  Thank you.

Comment: Use the Data Type "Range" instead of Variant.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would favor storing the range object itself rather than the address. But if you want the described solution, this will work:

```
Public Sub CommentLocator()

Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim cmt As Comment
Dim StartCell As Variant

Set Sht = Worksheets("Sheet06")

For Each cmt In Sht.Comments
    If cmt.Text = "$StartCell" Then
        StartCell = CStr(cmt.Parent.Address) ' <-- cmt.Parent is already a range object, no need for anything else. You can't use the Set keyword, though.
        Debug.Print StartCell
    End If
Next cmt

End Sub
```

To store the range object instead, change to:

```
Public Sub CommentLocator()

Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim cmt As Comment
Dim StartCell As Range

Set Sht = Worksheets("Sheet06")

For Each cmt In Sht.Comments
    If cmt.Text = "$StartCell" Then
        Set StartCell = cmt.Parent
        Debug.Print StartCell.Address
    End If
Next cmt

End Sub
```